# material design lite append icon

Tags: javascript, css, material-design

I am having issues with appending a  that uses material icons it seems not to load the css / js instead it shows the word check

-this part is coming out of stepper.js

```
var i = document.createElement('i');
                        i.style.className = 'material-icons';
                        var text = document.createTextNode('check');
                        i.appendChild(text);


                        elements.appendChild(i);
```

i am wondering how i would reload the js file or the reload the material font section?'

my header
- how I am loading the styesheet and js

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var uid = '{$smarty.session.ipet_user}';
 {literal} 

    function stylesheet(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('link');
            s.rel = 'stylesheet';
            s.async = false;
            s.href = url;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }

        function script(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = url;
            //s.defer = true;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }


         (function () {
                stylesheet('https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css');
                stylesheet('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
                stylesheet('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/user-theme/tpl-files/material.act.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/dropzone/dropzone.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/stepper/stepper.min.css');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/user-theme/tpl-files/style.css');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/style/newprofile.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/getmdlselect/getmdl-select.min.css');       

                script('https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js');
                script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js');
                script('https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js');
                script('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBk99v0F4qkmvxifqOD48YktK-QO-3kopI');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/google.js');
                script('plugins/getmdlselect/getmdl-select.min.js');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/facebook.js');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/newprofile.js');
                script('./templates/main/javascript/zipcode.js');
                script('plugins/stepper/v2/stepper.js');


         })();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the class for the element via `.className` not `.style.className`

```
i.className = 'material-icons';
```

```js
var elements = document.body;

var i = document.createElement('i');
i.className = 'material-icons';
var text = document.createTextNode('check');
i.appendChild(text);

elements.appendChild(i);
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
      function stylesheet(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('link');
            s.rel = 'stylesheet';
            s.async = false;
            s.href = url;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }

        function script(url) {
            var s = document.createElement('script');
            s.type = 'text/javascript';
            s.async = true;
            s.src = url;
            //s.defer = true;
            var x = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            x.appendChild(s);
        }


         (function () {
                stylesheet('https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css');
                stylesheet('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
                stylesheet('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/user-theme/tpl-files/material.act.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/dropzone/dropzone.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/stepper/stepper.min.css');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/user-theme/tpl-files/style.css');
                stylesheet('./templates/main/style/newprofile.css');
                stylesheet('plugins/getmdlselect/getmdl-select.min.css');       

                script('https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js');
                script('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js');
                script('https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js');
                script('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyBk99v0F4qkmvxifqOD48YktK-QO-3kopI');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/google.js');
                script('plugins/getmdlselect/getmdl-select.min.js');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/facebook.js');
                script('./templates/main/user-theme/javascript/newprofile.js');
                script('./templates/main/javascript/zipcode.js');
                script('plugins/stepper/v2/stepper.js');


         })();</script>
</body>
```